# Json does not store the value of the input file

Tags: php, html, json

Hello I recently created a form like this:

```
 <form method="post" Action="Save.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label>Nome:</label><br><br>
 <input name="Nome" ><br><br>
 <label>Imagem:</label><br><br>
 <div class='input-wrapper'>
  <label for='input-file'>
     Select a file
   </label>
 <input type="File" name="img" id="input-file"><br></div><br><label>Mensagem:</label><br><br><textarea name="msg"></textarea>
 <br><br>
 <input type="submit" class="btn_post">
 </form>
```

and not save.php looks like this:

```
<?php
// Here is more debug information:      
$values = json_encode($_POST);

// Stores received values ​​at the end of the file.
file_put_contents('save.json', $values, FILE_APPEND);
```

then when I send the form it looks like this in save.json:

```
{"Nome":"Nicolas","img":"aef9bd64-6990-4f08-8238-2baf005f42f7.jpg","msg":"Incredible"}
```

so far so good because I'm getting the name of the file that the user sent in the input File,
but I'm not receiving the file (Image), so I put this code in ** Save.php ** that looks like this:

```
  <?php
 //
 // Take the post request and transform it into JSON.
 $values = json_encode($_POST);

 // Stores received values ​​at the end of the file.
 file_put_contents('save.json', $values, FILE_APPEND);
 $uploaddir = 'img/';
 $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['img']['name']);

 echo '<pre>';
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
     echo "Valid file and sent successfully.\ N";
 } else {
     echo "Possible file upload attack! \ N";
 }

 echo 'Here is more debug information:';
 print_r($_FILES);

 print "</pre>";
```

so now i'm getting the file in the folder i declared in **$ uploaddir** plus save.json looks like this:

```
{"Nome":"Nicolas","msg":"Incredible"}
```

that is, I am no longer receiving the value of the input file **what is wrong?**

Comment: You will not find details of the file upload in the POST array - they will be in the `$_FILES`  array

Comment: And you need the path in your `$values` before you store the json

Comment: `FILE_APPEND` will not magically put commas between json object strings (nor will it wrap the whole file in square braces).  In other words, once you append data to the file a second time, you have invalid json.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but you could do something similar to this perhaps:

```
<?php

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_FILES ) ){
        
        # create the json variable and add attributes of the $_FILES object to the output
        $values=json_encode( $_POST );
        $values->filename=$_FILES['img']['name'];
        $values->size=$_FILES['img']['size'];
        
        # do the upload processing as previously
        $uploaddir = 'img/';
        $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename( $_FILES['img']['name'] );

        #move the file as per previous
        if( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile ) ) {
            $status="Arquivo válido e enviado com sucesso.";
        } else {
            $status="Possível ataque de upload de arquivo!";
        }   
        
        
        #store status of upload 
        $values->status=$status;
        $values->savepath=$uploadfile;
        
        # store with more info
        file_put_contents('save.json', $values, FILE_APPEND );
    
    }
```

Comment: Why `FILE_APPEND`?  `$status=echo...`??  Why declare `$status` at all?

Comment: ah- that was a mistook...never saw the `echo` in there. Why `FILE_APPEND`? Why not - if there is need to maintain file for each upload then keep adding to the file.... that's for the OP.